# How do we dynamically change the text in label widget of Tkinter according to the change of subscribed topic message?

Tags: python, tkinter, label, ros

I wanted to change the text of my label according to the topic message to which my node subscribes. But the problem is that the text in the label is not changing with the change of topic message. A portion of my code is given below:(I used the code to dynamically change the text in the label from https://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/629499-dynamically-displaying-time-using-tkinter-label)

```
v = StringVar()
v.set(distance)
self.clock = Label(frame, font=('times', 20, 'bold'), bg='green', textvariable = v)
self.clock.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
rate = rospy.Rate(2)

while not rospy.is_shutdown():
    rospy.Subscriber("distance", Float32, self.callback)
    v.set(distance)
    print("distance = %f", distance)
    frame.update_idletasks()
    rate.sleep()
```

Comment: I don't see the `distance` variable being updated anywhere. Does your `print` output the correct message?

Comment: distance variable is being updated inside the callback function of subscriber.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, your code (or at least the portion you posted) seems to be a messy one.

ROS talking,

- `define your subscriber in the initialization of the node` (not inside
  the while loop, that will create multiple subscribers instead!)
- `create a callback to get the messages` exchanged under that topic read the message
- `update your label` accordingly.

That being said, here's an example of how the code should look like : (fill in the blanks)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import rospy
from std_msgs.msg import Float32

def callback(data):
    distance = data.data
    rospy.loginfo(rospy.get_caller_id() + "distance = ", distance )
    #here update your label, I assume the following (maybe not correct)
    v = StringVar()
    v.set(distance)
    self.clock = Label(frame, font=('times', 20, 'bold'), bg='green', textvariable = v)
    self.clock.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

def listener():
    rospy.init_node('listener', anonymous=True)
    rospy.Subscriber("distance", Float32, self.callback)  
    # spin() simply keeps python from exiting until this node is stopped
    rospy.spin()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    listener()
```

Answer (score 0):

Sharing an example ROS subscriber to read 1 sensor and display the result using tkinter and a Class.  The display will update 1/second or whatever you set it to.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import time
from random import randint
import rospy
from std_msgs.msg import Int16

"""
subscribes to a ROS topic (/front_angle_low_res) which in my case is outputing an integer result and displays the result in a tkinter window

credit: https://www.pythontutorial.net/tkinter/tkinter-after/
credit: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EAAd5vXA8lE&t=260s

before running make sure to $ rostopic echo /front_angle_low_res to make sure data is available
This script can be started from the folder it resides in with $ python3 sensor_display.py

"""

class Display_Sensor_1(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.sub = rospy.Subscriber("/front_angle_low_res", Int16, self.callback_sensor_1)
        self.sensor_1_data = tk.IntVar()

        # configure the root window
        self.title('Sensor 1 Data')
        self.resizable(0, 0)
        self.geometry('250x80')
        self['bg'] = 'black'
        
        # change the background color to black
        self.style = ttk.Style(self)
        self.style.configure('TLabel', background='black', foreground='red')
        self.label = ttk.Label(self, text=self.get_sensor_data(), font=('Digital-7', 20))
        self.label.pack(expand=True)
        self.label.after(1000, self.update)     # schedule an update every 1 second

    def callback_sensor_1(self, data):   
        self.sensor_1_data = data.data
        #print(self.sensor_1_data)
        #rospy.loginfo(rospy.get_caller_id() + "I heard %s", data.data)

    def get_sensor_data(self):
        return self.sensor_1_data

    def update(self):
        """ update the label every 1 second """
        self.label.configure(text=self.get_sensor_data())
        self.label.after(1000, self.update)     # schedule another timer
 
if __name__ == "__main__":
    rospy.init_node('listener', anonymous=True)
    sensor = Display_Sensor_1()
    sensor.mainloop()
```

[gist link](https://gist.github.com/jones2126/a397b502923472f13c4529e2c9abd6c3)